# Fetching all private npm modules from an npmjs user

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-registry

I'm working on a task to migrate all of our npm modules from npmjs.com.
Problem is, all of our modules are stored under an npm user as private packages, and I can't find a way to consume all packages the user owns programmatically.

I found many examples that explain how to migrate a single package or a list of packages by name, but I've yet to understand how can I fetch every package a user owns to create that list.

There are a few modules that allow interacting with the NPM registry API, but I couldn't find out how to make them consume private scoped packages. I'm currently working with the [npm-registry-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-registry-fetch) to try and get an example query working with no luck.
This is the code I'm trying to run -

```
var npmFetch = require('npm-registry-fetch')


async function run() {
  var response = await npmFetch.json('@<scope redacted>/<package name redacted>',{token: '<token redacted>'})
}

run()
```

This code results in this error -
`HttpErrorGeneral: 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@<scope redacted>/<package name redacted> - Not found`

How can I successfully query these type of packages?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating that this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64110630/3833773) answer gave me the tools I've needed, performing the request as a curl command worked, so I'll just use that instead of using fancy registry clients. Thanks again internet stranger!